# C'è un modo di dire con l'espressione "la sonata di Čajkovskij"?

Tags: word-usage, idioms, etymology, phrase-request

Un mio conoscente mi ha spiegato qualche tempo fa un fatto che gli accadeva spesso da bambino. Gli piaceva arrampicarsi sugli alberi, ma poi non poteva scendere e suo padre doveva venir sempre per aiutarlo. Mi spiegava che, una volta a terra, tutta la faccenda finiva "con la sonata di Čajkovskij" o "come la sonata di Čajkovskij", qualcosa così, il che stava a significare che tutto finiva con una grande [suonata](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/suonata_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/).

Ho cercato informazione su Internet su questo modo di dire con l'espressione "la sonata di Čajkovskij", ma non ho trovato nulla. Mi potreste confermare se questa espressione si usa in alcuna regione o in tutta Italia? Se è così, come si usa e qual è il suo origine?

Comment: Non conosco questo modo di dire (e forse faceva parte del “lessico famigliare” del tuo amico), ma intervengo da buon pignuolo in servizio permanente effettivo per far notare la vexata quaestio della traslitterazione del cognome del compositore russo: la tua versione è “alla tedesca” (con quel “tch” per rendere un suono poco familiare al tedesco, ma presente in russo come in italiano, spagnolo – anche in catalano? – e molte altre lingue). La traslitterazione scientifica è “Čajkovskij”.

Comment: @DaG: In catalano si scrive Txaikovski (il suono di cui hai parlato in catalano si scrive "tx"). Adesso modifico il testo della domanda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guarda, io credo che sia un modo di dire locale dovuto al fatto che, molti anni fa, il Milan (una delle due squadre di calcio di Milano) aveva un allenatore molto simpatico, famoso per le sue battute, che rispondeva al nome di Nereo Rocco. Una volta il Milan doveva incontrare una squadra straniera, il cui allenatore si chiamava proprio Čajkovskij. All'intervistatore che gli chiedeva un pronostico sulla partita, Rocco rispose con la frase poi divenuta famosa tra i milanisti: "Beh, speriamo di assistere alla sonata di Čajkovskij..." giocando sul termine sonata, che oltre che indicare una composizione musicale, in gergo si usa con il significato di una serie di percosse e quindi di una sonora sconfitta. 
 Un'altra battuta di Rocco prima di una partita contro una squadra molto forte: all'intervistatore che concludeva la sua intervista con la frase "Allora signor Rocco cosa possiamo dire? Che vinca il migliore!" Rocco rispose: "Mah... speriamo proprio di no!"
La più celebre delle frasi di Rocco è stata messa tra leggi di Murphy: rivolgendosi al suo stopper che si chiamava Rosato e tremava di paura perché doveva marcare un attaccante molto pericoloso, gli disse: "Adesso tu, Rosato, entri in campo e butti giù tutto quello sta sopra l'erba... e si ti capita di colpire la palla... pazienza!"

Comment: Questo [articolo della Gazzetta dello Sport](http://www.gazzetta.it/Calcio/Super-Match/10-04-2013/nedved-inzaghi-jovetic-bayern-ricordi-loro-gol-92923286182.shtml) spiega qualcosa su l'aneddoto che hai menzionato.